# My ASP database won't allow me to add a second user even thought UserID is a primary key and has identity set?

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

So i seem to be getting this error when trying to insert more than one user into my ASP.NET SQL database. One user can register succesfully and their data shows in the database no problem, but for some reason multiple users gives me this problem.

Inner Exception 2:
SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

I've done some research on this problem and changed my database a lot to see if I could fix the problem, but so far nothing has worked. It would appear as if my UsersID isn't actually accending like it should be when a new user is added to the database through my registration page, just for reference, here is my SQL table code!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserID]          int NOT NULL Identity(1,1),
    [FirstName]       VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [LastName]        VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [EmailID]         VARCHAR (254)    NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth]     DATETIME         NULL,
    [Password]        NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [IsEmailVerified] BIT              NOT NULL,
    [ActivationCode]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY ([UserID]) 
);
```

Any idea what the problem I'm having is since I assumed setting an identity for my UserID primary key would solve the problem?
Thanks!

```
//Registration Action
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Registration POST action
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude ="IsEmailVerified, ActivationCode")]User user)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            String message = "";


            //Model Validation
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                #region //Email already exists
                var isExist = isEmailExist(user.EmailID);
                if(isExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email Already Exists");
                    return View(user);
                }
                #endregion

                #region Generate Activation Code
                user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                #endregion

                #region Password Hashing
                user.Password = Crypto.Hash(user.Password);
                user.ConfirmPassword = Crypto.Hash(user.ConfirmPassword); // 
                #endregion

                user.IsEmailVerified = false;

                #region Save Data To Database
                using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
                {
                    dc.Users.Add(user);
                    dc.SaveChanges();

                    //Send Email To User
                    SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.EmailID, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
                    message = "Registration Success!" + " " + "Account activation link" + "has been sent to your email id:" + user.EmailID;

                    Status = true;

                }
                #endregion



            }

            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(user);
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Store.Models
{

    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMetadata
    {
        [Display(Name ="First Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email ID required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }


        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false, ErrorMessage ="Password is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage ="Minimum 6 characters required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password and password do not match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


    }

}
```

Comment: please share your c# insert code as well

Comment: Code has been updated!:)

Comment: can you check what is the value of user.UserID ? hence its not assigned here.

Comment: Pasting your User class would help, too. It looks like you're using Entity Framework, did you add a `[Key]` attribute to your `UserId` property?

Comment: Added the user class into my question, and if by add a key attribute you mean apply a primary key to my UserID row inside the SQL tables, then yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

your userId column is not nullabale and you are not sending any value into this column, by default is going as 0. and in the database its getting value to auto increment is not working. try this code and let me know.

```
#region Save Data To Database
using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
{
    var maxUserId = dc.Users.Max(x=>x.UserId);
    if(maxUserId !=null)
        user.UserId = maxUserId + 1;

    dc.Users.Add(user);
    dc.SaveChanges();

    //Send Email To User
    SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.EmailID, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
    message = "Registration Success!" + " " + "Account activation link" + "has been sent to your email id:" + user.EmailID;

    Status = true;

}
#endregion
```